# Взаимодействие JSF с Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsf

Все добрый день. Интересует вопрос можно ли использовать связку JSF + Spring MVC. И если да то меня интересует вопрос, как представления будут связываться с моделью, ведь у JSF и Spring MVC различные контексты. Буду благодарен за примеры (желательно на аннотациях).

Comment: А зачем вам такой гибрид?

Comment: Да захотелось PrimeFaces использовать

Comment: а почему тогда не использовать Java EE? я нашел вот такой [пример](https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-spring-web-mvc-primefaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде всего надо понимать разницу в подходах. Spring MVC, как и следует из названия - следует архитектуре [Model-View-Controller](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller). Центральным элементом web-приложения и точкой входа для запросов служит контроллер, инкапсулирующий в себе всю программную логику. JSF же компонентно-ориентированный. Точкой входа служит шаблон, который содержит компоненты, каждый из которых содержит в себе свою часть программной логики. В JSF инкапсулируют в себе программную логику так называемые backing beans. Они создаются и внедряются в контекст страницы контейнером JSF. Поэтому нельзя интегрировать JSF и Spring MVC, но можно JSF и Spring. Для этого достаточно настроить JSF так, чтобы его контекстом управлял Spring, заменить один контейнер на другой:

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>
                org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  ...
</web-app>
```

Кроме того, с JSF можно интегрировать [Spring Web Flow](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-faces.html).