# Spring, подключить PrimeFaces

Tags: java, spring, framework, primefaces

Начал изучать прайм фейсес. Не могу его подключить, делаю все по разным мануалам в сети. На данный момент не находит сами вьюхи, хотя до переделывание на xhtml все работало, конфиг:

```
    @Configuration
public class BeanConfig {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Gradle:

```
    @Configuration
public class BeanConfig {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Новичок, сильно не ругайте)

Comment: По моему нужно в конфиге заменить вью класс с JstlView на что то другое ..

Comment: Primrfaces это JSF. а JSF, как я где-то видел, с огромным трудом прикручивается к Spring. JSF и Spring берут на себя туже самую работу, только выполняют по разному. Они скорее конкуренты чем  дополнение друг другу.

Comment: [Ответ на похожий вопрос "Взаимодействие JSF с Spring MVC"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/651881/204271)

Comment: мне такое сказали на практике сделать. Там парни уже делали такое, так что сделать можно и говорят что без проблем

Comment: Можно, но не нужно.