# Отображение списка объектов в таблице jsf

Tags: java, spring, jsf, xhtml

Здравствуйте!

Есть метод findAll в контроллере:

```
@Controller("companyController")
public class CompanyController {

@Autowired
private CompanyService companyService;

private String name;

private int id;

public String saveCompany(){
    Company company = new Company();
    company.setName(name);
    companyService.save(company);

    return "WEB-INF/login";
}

public String removeCompany(){
    companyService.remove(id);
    return "WEB-INF/login";
}

public List<Company> findAll(){

    return companyService.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/companies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView companies(ModelAndView modelAndView){
    modelAndView.setViewName("companies");

    return modelAndView;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Который должен выводить список компаний из БД.
Каким образом сделать отображение на view?
Сделал что-то вроде:

```
    <h:dataTable value="#{companyController.findAll}" var="company">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Id"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{company.id}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Name"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{company.name}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Но не работает. Выводит:

```
/login.xhtml @37,69 value="#{companyController.findAll}": Property 'findAll' not found on type org.probation.controllers.CompanyController
```

Возможно, это и вообще не то, что нужно, конечно.

Как пример, то, что хочу получить со страницы jsp ниже. Нужно похожее на jsf.

```
<table class="tg">
    <tr>
        <th width="80">ID</th>
        <th width="120">Name</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${companyList}" var="company">
        <tr>
            <td>${company.id}</td>
            <td><a href="/companydata/${company.id}" target="_blank">${company.name}</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Взаимодействие JSF с Spring MVC](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651691/%d0%92%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-jsf-%d1%81-spring-mvc)

Comment: Есть ли у вас такое свойство `findAll` ? возможно вы хотели вызвать метод `findAll()` ?

Comment: Да. Не тот метод добавил. Прошу прощения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел.
Наверняка не самое правильное и выглядит, конечно, ужасно, но то, что нужно, в принципе, делает. Логика стала ясна.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{companyController.findAll()}" var="company">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Id"/>
        </f:facet>
        #{company.id}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Name"/>
        </f:facet>
        #{company.name}
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: и сам методо findAll поправил, чтоб возвращал список